# Conky fails to run on Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, xubuntu, conky

I installed [Conky](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky) on Xubuntu 18.04.  I tried adding it to **Session and Startup**, but it *doesn't* start up after login.  I then tried running it in the terminal.

```
$ conky
conky: error while loading shared libraries: libImlib2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Since the package [`libimlib2-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libimlib2-dev/filelist) contains the file `libImlib2.so`, I installed this package, and ran `file` out of curiosity.  I was surprised that the system complained "broken link".

```
$ file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImlib2.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImlib2.so: broken symbolic link to libImlib2.so.1.4.10
```

How to get Conky running on Xubuntu?

Comment: Did you install the github version or the one from the 18.04 repos?  I did the latter and have had no problems.  I have just libimlib2 installed, not the -dev version.

Comment: HI. Did you compile conky from git sources or install from ubuntu repository?

Comment: You could try Conky version 1.9 instead of 1.10.

Comment: @OrganicMarble `sudo apt-get install conky-all lm-sensors`

Comment: @cmak.fr Thanks for comment.  I've done the later.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks for suggestion.  I've downloaded the _current_ version of Conky on other GNU/Linux distros _without_ problem, despite a plethora of reported bugs from other users.

Comment: @GNUSupporter I had bugs too. For the longest time my 1.9 script wouldn't run in 1.10. But now with `1.10.8` the script runs fine. Not sure when bugs were fixed but I did a fresh install Aug 1, 2018 and problems were gone.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It's great to hear that.  As I'm the *owner* of this question, I'll be automatically notified in case of a comment or an answer, so you may comment without tagging post owner next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @OrganicMarble's comment, I know that I should install the package [`libimlib2`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libimlib2/filelist) instead of [`libimlib2-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libimlib2-dev/filelist).

I checked the path of installed files by running `dpkg-query -L libimlib2`, and I found the library `libimlib2.so.1` *missing*.

As a result, I *removed* the irrelevant `libimlib2-dev`, and *reinstalled* (i.e. remove and install) `libimlib2` and `conky-all` from Ubuntu's *official* packages.

To check whether the setup is correct, I've run the *same* `dpkg-query` again: the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImlib2.so.1` appears at the bottom of the list.  It serves as a "symbolic link to `libImlib2.so.1.4.10`".

Now, Conky can be launched on Xubuntu 18.04.

[image: Conky running on Xubuntu 18.04]

P.S. The above picture shows Conky *1.10.8* installed from Ubuntu's `apt` package manager.  I installed Xubuntu 18.04 alongside with M$ Win* 10 late June, which was *four months later* than the compilation date of my copy of Conky 1.10.8.

```
$ conky -v
conky 1.10.8 compiled Wed Feb 28 17:11:42 UTC 2018 for Linux 4.4.0-101-generic x
86_64
...
```